# UIButton Not Receiving IBAction After Storyboard Modification

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, xcode7.3

I have a UIButton in my Storyboard, placed inside a scrollview which was working fine earlier. It would do its intended task on click. I had to change the storyboard for some enhancement wherein the position of the button changed a bit.

Now the button does not receive the click event. I checked using the view-debugger and there is nothing blocking the button. The IBAction is linked to the button as it should be. But, still the click does not work.

I do not want to re-do all the design all over again. Is there anyway to find out what is causing this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you solve this issue? My problem is exactly same.

Comment: I had to re-do it.